# How to upload a spreadsheet to google drive by PHP with defined language is German?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I try to save a Spreadsheet at Google Drive.

The Spreadsheet is created with `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet`.
I use `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile` to upload.
All works fine, but the language of the file is `english`. I want to change the langage of the file to German (example for `de_DE`) during my upload process in PHP.

I just find the optPraam `ocrLanguage` but not to send country code or language code.
MimeType = `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`

How can I switch the language of the file to german by PHP? Not by the google Drive UI.

Comment: Did you try checking the manual (Google, good) https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/settings/

Comment: Yes, nur without success

Comment: So you didnt see `$locale = 'pt_br';  $validLocale = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Settings::setLocale($locale);` Or you tried it and it didnt do what you wanted? Which one ???

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when the file is uploaded by converting to Google Spreadsheet, it seems that Drive API has no methods for changing the locale and the timezone. So as a workaround, for the uploaded Spreadsheet, how about achieving your goal using Sheets API? When Sheets API is used, the locale and the timezone of the Spreadsheet can be changed. The sample script for this is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please use your `$client`, and please set the Spreadsheet ID of the uploaded Spreadsheet. And, as a scope, I used `Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS`.

```php
$client = ### // Please use this from your script.
$fileID = '###'; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.

$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$requests = [
    new \Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
        'updateSpreadsheetProperties' => [
            'properties' => [
                'locale' => 'de_DE',
                'timeZone' => 'Europe/Berlin'
            ],
            'fields' => 'locale,timeZone'
        ]
    ])
];
$batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(['requests' => $requests]);
$response = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($fileID, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

- When this script is run, the locale and timeZone of the Spreadsheet is as follows.

  ```
    {
      "properties": {
        "locale": "de_DE",
        "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
      }
    }
  ```
- If your locale and timeZone are different from above, please modify them.

#### References:

- [UpdateSpreadsheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatespreadsheetpropertiesrequest)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)